# Definition of convergent sequence in topological space

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence

The book I'm reading says:

**If $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence of points in $(X,T)$ and $x \in (X,T)$, the sequence is said to converge to $x$ iff for each open set $U \in T$, there exists an $n_0 \in \Bbb N$ such that $x_n \in U$, for every $n \ge n_0$.**

Is this definition wrong?  Wouldn't $x$ have to be in $U$ for this to make sense?  Otherwise you could just choose an open set that has no points of $x_n$ in it and it won't be convergent.

Shouldn't it be:

**If $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence of points in $(X,T)$ and $x \in (X,T)$,    the sequence is said to converge to $x$ iff for each open set $U \in    T$ such that $x \in U$, there exists an $n_0 \in \Bbb N$ such that    $x_n \in U$, for every $n \ge n_0$.**

Comment: You may wish to note that sequences do not capture the topology for general topological spaces like they do for metric spaces, for example. For instance, continuity of functions cannot be characterized by the limits of sequences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right. Another way to say this would be, "for each open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$, ...".